# Обновление сайта (частое улучшение): какие программы?

Tags: обновление, php

Всем привет.

Хотел бы поинтересоваться удобным способом обновления сайта. То есть, в чем проблема?

- Если использовать denwer - на нем редактировать сайт - заливать по ftp, то будут ошибки, так как на denwer'е и хостинге сайт работает по-разному.
- Если редактировать онлайн (подключиться по ftp и редактировать), то пользователи будут видеть все ошибке при разработке (не вариант вообще).

Если мысля, что можно сделать сборку самостоятельно, не через денвер. Думаю, поможет.

Так вот, как кто работает с обновлением сайта? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: используй CMS! Настрой её один раз на хосте и локалке, 1 файл всегда затрагивается ну 2, остальные можешь менять как душе угодно.

Comment: У меня своя разработанная система. Делал все сам. Поэтому нужны уникальные решения.

Comment: Так что мешает сделать себе эти решения, мы же не знаем как у тебя и за что зацеплена система с чем и как она работает. придумай файл конфигурации и меняй в нем параметры, а вообще если уж делать систему, то и работать она должна как локально на денвере по дефолтным параметрам так и на любом хостинге. ИМХО!

Comment: А вообще тестишь локально и просто по FTP заливаешь сайт с обновленными файлами.

Comment: @Shrek очередной раз солидарен!

Comment: Фреймворк Code-igniter лежит в основе. Shrek, я не спрашивал, как улучшать сайт при помощи денвера, я просил подсказать альтернативу.

Comment: Да как же ты не поймешь, что нет альтернативы. Либо перейти на нормальный хостинг с поддержкой того что тебе нужно, либо так и оставить проект до момента появления денег, чтобы купить нормальный хостинг.

Вопрос в другом, как можно извратиться с уже готовым фреймворком, чтобы он работал локально а на серваке не работал!

Решения я уже писал

\+ пишешь сайт на локалке, заливаешь на хостинг и настраиваешь.

\+ обновляешь его локально, заливаешь на хостинг, смотришь результат.

тут то все просто должно быть. Проще уж некуда объяснять.

Comment: Что вы мудрите? Используйте русскую версию Adobe Dreamweaver CS3, заливаешь логин и пароль хостинга и работай !!!! Adobe Dreamweaver можно найти в google . 

Comment: @Programist Syvorov, *рукалицо*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как вариант:

- Домен test.yourdomain.com (в htaccess добавить `deny from all` и `allow from твой IP`)
- Дубль базы данных

При внесении изменений сайт закрыть на профилактику, обновить БД, заменить измененные файлы!

Comment: Хорошо, что должна дать запись в htaccess? Как я понял где IP - это должен быть ip хоста? С БД нужно что-то другое придумать, так как у меня не блог, а приложение, контентом управляют пользователи. Думаю создать лишь тестовый бд с тестовыми записями.

Comment: Нет, именно твой IP, при этом тестовый сайт будешь видеть только ты(минус конечно если IP динамический)

Comment: Жаль, но IP динамический. Но, прочем все равно не плохой вариант. Как я понял вас, нужно создать копию сайта на поддомене и создать новую базу и сцепить. Как раз, параметры сервера одни и те же, таким образом можно перекидывать файлы с тестового сайта на основной. Но как быть с IP?

Comment: Можно без htaccess. Просто закрыть тестовй сайт от индексации ПС'ми! Я не думаю что кто-то будет руками вбивать test.yourdomain.com, к тому же где test может быть что угодно, хоть **wtf**)))

З.Ы. Поняли верно!

Comment: Удобно. Спасибо. =)

Comment: @Palmervan, зря так думаете)

Answer (score 2):

Для разработки использую Git (и, считаю, работа без системы контроля версий — неудобно и вообще прошлый век, если не пользуетесь — рекомендую попробовать). Аналогичное можно сделать, как минимум, с Mercurial и Bazaar (что актуально для многих, т.к. у git под windows есть сложности и подводные камни) — вопрос чисто предпочтений.

Сразу говорю, речь не о entry-level shared-хостинге, там такое не прокатит. Метод требует ssh-доступ и установленный git — соответственно, подходит для продвинутых shared-хостингов (типа WebFaction), VPS и «настоящих» «железных» серверов.

Использую git с post-receive хуком для обновления working tree и пинка сервера/демонов.

Создается два git-репозитория:

- **Hub** — «центральный» bare-репозиторий, из которого будут клонироваться все остальные и в который будут поступать все коммиты. Заодно на него же можно натравить Redmine/ChiliProject/Trac/gitweb.
- **Prime** — обычный репозиторий, на рабочее дерево которого смотрит веб-сервер.

В `post-receive` хуке Hub'а прописываем, чтобы все коммиты поступали в Prime, что-то в таком духе:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /var/www # Путь к «Prime»
env -i git pull hub master
```

В `post-commit` хуке Prime'а (на случай внезапных правок «на живую»), соответственно:

```
#!/bin/sh
git push hub
```

И, если оно доступно — тем или иным способом (.htaccess, конфигурация сервера, права файловой системы) прикрываем `/var/www/.git` от доступа через web (чтобы никто не сделал клон по http)

Сценарий работы, соответственно:

```
git clone example.org:/srv/website
# Запускаем $EDITOR, делаем свою работу.
git commit -a -m "Поправили фичи, добавили баги"
git push
```

По-английски, про то же самое (разве что `unset GIT_DIR` мне как-то не по душе, лучше `env -i`), но чуть подробнее и нагляднее: [A web-focused Git workflow](http://joemaller.com/990/a-web-focused-git-workflow/).

Comment: Выглядит удобно, но в тоже время не понятно, так как слышу о этом первый раз. =) Буду гуглить. =)

Answer (score 0):

Поднимаешь сабдомен на Денвере, используешь стандартные настройки Денвера - и все работает и так отлично. Решение самостоятельной сборки потянет за собой больше проблем чем  пользы

Answer (score 0):

Обновляю всё через ftp, в онлайн режиме. Ошибки показываю только себе.